# Building a deck... Pier Size / Loading Question

Tags: fence, footings

I am building a deck. I have most of things sized out properly I think.  I just want to confirm that 12" piers are enough for what I am doing.  This is a freestanding deck next to a pool.

Did I draw my areas for loading pretty close?  The largest one I have is about 21 sq ft, which means the 12" piers should be plenty.

Beams are doubled 2x8, joists are 2x8.   All posts will be > 1' from edge of pool, but I had to get pretty close due to the wonkiness in the lower left corner.  (Even still, that last joist has a cantilever of about 1'9", so I could push it back a hair more if needed

[image: Piers]

[image: Joists]

Comment: Although there are probably experts on this forum that could provide an answer for you, this is a safety question and you should not rely on on-line answers. Who is responsible if you follow our advice and an accident results? You will need to get a local building permit anyway so you should consult local experts.

Comment: Are you asking about 12" **depth** for piers? Unless your in the deep south a 12" depth for the piers doesn't seem like enough because of possible frost. You need to be sure they're below the frostline. In Colorado, for example, it's 36".

Comment: @HoneyDo very valid point, however I assumed (and we all know what happens) that OP was asking about a 12" **diameter** pier of appropriate depth. Maybe he'll come back to clarify...

Comment: Yes, I was looking at 12" diameter pads, at about 42" depth

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a expert but the answer likely depends on exactly where you live. When I built my deck in Maryland the footings needed to 30" deep and 18" in diameter (for the bottom 8").

See [local ordinances](https://library.municode.com/md/howard_county/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=HOCOCO_TIT3BU_SUBTITLE_1BUCO_S3.105ELVECHIN) for Howard County Maryland.

If you are lucky your jurisdiction may publish their requirements. If they don't publish them you could give your local permit office a call.

Jonathan

Comment: As an aside if your soil is anything like mine (mixed clay and rocks) you might want to consider increasing you beam size / checking maximum spans so you can reduce the number of footings and save yourself some digging.

Comment: I don't see too many posts that could be removed. Maybe convert 4 posts to 3 on the long 15' run or convert 3 to 2 on the right hand 9' run? Everything else is 2 posts, 1 beam...

Comment: Agreed. Though you could probably also merge the two separate beams with four post on the front right to one beam. At least in my jurisdiction you are allowed a 2' overhang. If you converted the 4->3, 3->2 and the 2 separate beams to one with 2 posts then you would save 4 posts (and the footing underneath). It all depends on how bad the digging is where he lives.

Comment: Fair enough, point.

Comment: thanks for the insight, guys...  As far as combining the 2 beams to 1, I don't think it's possible - I'm trying to keep any part of my holes (14" holes for 12" footings) at least 12" away from the pool edge.  Assuming I "nearly" center my post in the holes, my cantilevar on the joist ended up being a few inches more than 2' at the worst case area.  (I think just the troubles with working around a pool)

Comment: As far as changing the 4 posts to 3... That puts my PSF for those footings at about 1300-1400.. which I think would be pushing a bit high for my crummy clay soil on 12" pads.

Comment: And, removing the middle post on the 3 makes my 2x2x8 beam a hair undersized for the "worst case" 9' span...

Comment: Have you checked your 12" pad is acceptable. It seems way smaller than I would expect.